# Type 'string' is not assignable to type keyof in Immutable.js

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I got this typing error when trying to use immutable js reviver from `fromJS` function.

Check this [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyyIcAthAFzLphSgDmA3AUXPZcQK6kBG0z%20AL4ECMTiARhgAexDIYUaaQBSAZQAULIsgBW6AGpwANpw7iA1iGkB3EABotRKBABuwF9AD8VTYW1FzCABPKho6EHpkAB8uXmgHP38XY1MqAHI0-yJHZABKZABeAD5kCytbLVyqMps5PETkZzBOKDkMgSJBAQIIAA8AB2koMHlxSRk5UmkAEwgjACVXd2gAHgAVIvVSOH7%206CoABThh4GN1oqrkdUCQ5ABRXtpEMBWb6RhkNbtqWgYi7%20SJg4cBAQXyxWQIKCOGyfiaLTk12CAJSEHBJS2Oz2UAAdAALODoADytgOimxYCCSLByE8yG2u2gAG0bgBdZBUBRKNTqQGmXK5ATCfAEBCyGj0mZzQqS2YLJYeKArDDQTb1IgkcjpMB4pSEtIEQSCkT4LkqDTYQTfKZy3ImoA), I could reproduce it there.

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

// Taken from typing definition of Immutable.js with some modification to simplify it
// https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/blob/main/type-definitions/immutable.d.ts#L4955
function fromJS(
    jsValue: unknown,
    reviver?: (
      key: string | number,
      value: ''      
    ) => unknown
  ): unknown {
    return '';
  };

// My custom function for reviver, 
// I used `Extract` to ensure that it gets the string only
export function modelReviver<T>(mapper: Partial<T>): (key: Extract<keyof T, string>, value: any) => any {  
  return (key, value) => (mapper.hasOwnProperty(key) ? mapper[key] : fromJS(value));
}

const model = modelReviver<User>({
  name: 'thomas'
});

fromJS({}, model) // typing error
```

The error said

```
Types of parameters 'key' and 'key' are incompatible.
  Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'keyof User'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof User'
```

I'm aware that the issue is regarding the `key` parameter and since the `key` is from Immutable.js I couldn't just modify it. Wondering why `Extract` that I specified on `modelReviver` couldn't solve the issue.

Does anyone have a clue why this happened? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to pass in a generic to `fromJS`, the only way to do this, is to type the key as what's expected `string | number`.

Here is a sample bellow:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

function fromJS(
    jsValue: unknown,
    reviver?: (
      key: string | number,
      value: ''      
    ) => unknown
  ): unknown {
    return '';
  };

export function modelReviver<T>(mapper: Partial<T>): (key: string | number, value: any) => any {  
  return (key, value) => (mapper.hasOwnProperty(key) ? mapper[key as keyof T] : fromJS(value));
}

const model = modelReviver<User>({
  name: 'thomas'
});

fromJS({}, model)
```

Comment: Thank you mate! It works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this breaks any of your functionality as I have little context of exactly what you are trying to do. But you can get rid of the error by saying that you want key of user in fromJS, like this:

```
function fromJS(
    jsValue: unknown,
    reviver?: (
      key: keyof User,
      value: ''      
    ) => unknown
  ): unknown {
    return '';
  };
```

You could expand upon this to make fromJS generic using keyof T in it as well.

The problem you were facing comes from string not being assignable to keyof User as keyof User is MORE specific than string.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Appreciate your help. In this case, I couldn't change the definition of `fromJS`. It is from typing definition here https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js/blob/main/type-definitions/immutable.d.ts#L4955